# Showing position and momentum relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum, wavefunction

I am trying to show this :[image]

I have tried a couple of different approaches and I decided to stick with this one.
Here is my working but I am stuck and I don't know how to proceed, what are the following steps needed to be taken, or if these steps are wrong, what is the correct approach? Pls let me know if anything is unclear:[image]

Here is another approach I tried, but I'm not sure that its valid: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The derivation will depend upon what you know (or are given to assume) other than your first equation. For instance, if you are given the position-momentum uncertainty relations (or that momentum and position are conjugate), then you can note that $X$ is Hermitian and apply the $X$ operator to the momentum bra on the left. If you are not really given anything (including the definition of $X$) then you may need to define $X$ as the generator of changes in momentum and use a derivation along the lines of that on pages 43-46 of J.J. Sakurai and Jim Napolitano's second edition of "Modern Quantum Mechanics." (This derivation is one way to develop the connection between momentum and the partial derivative with respect to position.)

Aiding you further may require more information.